# Aptana studio3 Eclipse plugin install process fails in specific conditions - what's the right processv to follow

Tags: plugins, aptana, multiple-versions

I had first installed Eclipse with Aptana studio 2 plugin.

Later I would test studio3 and installed as stand alone.

Now I wish to migrate from studio 2 to 3 (very few projects) plugin, import project from 2 and 3 workspaces versions.

I have followed the instructions but probably missed something or several things.

**I got this long error message**

`enter code hereCannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 2.0.5.1278522500-5-7857HJ97CFF61HN1HZHtem5tN7 (com.aptana.ide.feature.studio.feature.group 2.0.5.1278522500-5-7857HJ97CFF61HN1HZHtem5tN7)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar 2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144)
    Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Core 3.0.7.1325099706-BJ7F8LBTDuY5meBG31DC34EVnIM5 (com.aptana.feature.feature.group 3.0.7.1325099706-BJ7F8LBTDuY5meBG31DC34EVnIM5)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group [2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M)
    To: com.aptana.feature.feature.group [3.0.7.1325099706-BJ7F8LBTDuY5meBG31DC34EVnIM5]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group 2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar [2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar [2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana SecureFTP Support 2.0.4.1278035782-77-7878BQS8KNJOC040234995BA2 (com.aptana.ide.feature.secureftp.feature.group 2.0.4.1278035782-77-7878BQS8KNJOC040234995BA2)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group [2.0.2.1277398033-3-123884A9144]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 2.0.5.1278522500-5-7857HJ97CFF61HN1HZHtem5tN7 (com.aptana.ide.feature.studio.feature.group 2.0.5.1278522500-5-7857HJ97CFF61HN1HZHtem5tN7)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.secureftp.feature.group [2.0.4.1278035782-77-7878BQS8KNJOC040234995BA2]`

**My questions are :**
   In described process, studio 2 and 3 can be normally installed and simultaneously used. The natural restriction is : don't use both on same projects...

- do exist a problem when both studio3 alone and plugin are installed ?, if it is how to solve it : "principle" ?
- if I want to migrate to plugin alone, how can I import the projects operation which needs to import the project from studio3 alone workspace to studio3 plugin workspace. If I had to uninstall to current installations before installing studio3, how could I presserve his workspace to import from later. This seems not to be the right way, but better solve the dependencies problem.

Then, How to satisfy the dependencies ? How install the 3 versions and do what I want after import.

Thanks

Trebly

---

I don't wish to re-install all Eclipse because I want and need to install studio3.

I read in "migration"

> Migrating Projects Aptana Studio 2 and Aptana Studio 3 have different
>   workspaces, so you can use the two products simultaneously. In order
>   to work with a project in Aptana Studio 3, you will want to import
>   your project from one workspace to the other. It is not recommended to
>   edit a project in both Studio 2 and Studio 3. Once you import a
>   project, it is suggested you stick with Studio 3 for editing.>

So It seems possible to install studio3 plugin into Eclipse while sudio2 is already installed and after import from the right workspace the studio2 projects that we want to continue with studio3.

It is what I want do, as it is described into documentation.

Comment: From the log, it looks like you are trying to install Studio 3.x over an Eclipse with Studio 2.x. Try starting with a clean Eclipse, or a fresh new Studio 3 install.

Comment: Ei, I don't wish to re-install all Eclipse because I want to install studio3. I read in "migration" <Migrating Projects
Aptana Studio 2 and Aptana Studio 3 have different workspaces, so you can use the two products simultaneously. In order to work with a project in Aptana Studio 3, you will want to import your project from one workspace to the other.>

 It is not recommended to edit a project in both Studio 2 and Studio 3. Once you import a project, it is suggested you stick with Studio 3 for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinstall Eclipse and all plugins, is there a reason you do not want to simply uninstall Studio 2 from your Eclipse install (the plugin version) and then install Studio 3 plugin on that same base?

If this is an acceptable approach, uninstalling is easy. I'm on Eclipse 3.6 but recall this approach for several versions back.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Click the link for "Already Installed"
3. Select the Aptana Studio 2 option from the list of installed plugin/services
4. Press "Uninstall"
5. Restart Eclipse
6. Use Help -> Install New Software again to install Aptana Studio 3 per usual

As for the project files (i.e., the .project file Eclipse and Studio create when you make a project), I would not think it's possible to have two copies of Studio running on the same Eclipse install. That might not be right but I have yet to see a case where I can have two versions of a plugin installed and active at the same time.

Comment: Hi, Craig Because of dependencies it seems impossible to install plugins studio2 and 3 to work into Eclipse. After uninstall of studio2 plugin and another uncompatible link, I could install studio3 and many others components and make upgrades of other components compatible with studio3. So the Doc about Aptana plugins installation seems wrong on this point. Nevertheless if somebody want to have the two versions a standalone installation is always possible. Eclipse have made his job about integration and upgrades. I will look at the ECLIPSE capability to tell which upgrades are linked and how

Answer (score 0):

Answer to last answer. text too long for a simple comment.

OK, thanks, I had already had to use it for another incompatibility, so I know this process it defines that studio2 is uninstalled before installing studio3.

As I saidn it is not what is said into upgrade documentation of APTANA.

If the workspace of studio2 is protected then I can import the projects to studio3 workspace even studio2 had been uninstalled. 
I don't found till now any reason to maintain studio 2.

### **About the fact to maintain or not sudio2 in use while studio3 is used too**

But, as it was proposed into the update process, I had decided to do the same that I always do in my configurations when there are two major versions compatible of a software, I keep for a while the ancient version to be protected against any difference.

I practice this commonly in development, when some bugs or compatibility problems appears, sometimes a long time after the installation, it have been always very useful.

**General remarks about upgrades and data and developed soft portability (for whom is interested in this linked subject):**

The last main experience of this was for me, a few month ago, on Microsoft Office VBA development, I had to re-install the 2003 version - with many difficulties on a virtual computer running XP SP3 -to be able to update VBA code - 80,000 lines of an application, that I had been unable to make run on win7-64x (activeX, dll, code).

Another case was on the behavior of VLC transcoding video.

At this time I need to maintain operational version with data on six versions of tikiwiki of the main repository and 12 of mine. To have time to develop, check developments on each version (bring these to 2 lts version before) commit to the last operational release it is a lot of work which become to be impossible to manage without good trackers and comparison tools. I need continuity in project management tools but enhancements too.

This is the main problem for my Eclipse installation of which I hope important earn of time the problem is that while in one year I develop twenty enhancements - the main rhythm of the team generate at the same time a major release, six secondary and one LTS... I must assure a parallelism which cost me a lot. I must find back all items of changes of code, complex conflicts and quickly make upgrades on new versions.

Another important case had been with php 5.1 to 5.3 I that I maintain quite a long time - it is not immediate - the two versions for a while for test on a same server. I found with this many change to do on code, definitions of parameters and a "pseudo bug : change of rule on parameters.

For the example of Aptana, may be, to obtain full compatibility sharing some parts of soft you should disable some (FTP ?) parts of studio2 installation, install studio 3 and link again studio2 to the new version. 
This is very frequent with Dll. If well organized the new functions gets a new num ("function_1, function_2...) then when a num is well associated to a version or a sequence of versions, if you keep into the dll all the functions for old version running with, the dll can be full compatible.

Sorry for the length but I have been happy and lucky to have organized like this most of migrations that I had to manage.

### **For the case, I should wish such an answer**

****To obtain full compatibility which needs sharing obviously some parts of soft you must disable some (FTP ?) parts of studio2 installation, install studio 3 and link again studio2 to the new version compatible parts (automatically uninstalled at level studio2).But answer too for example that if the standalone installations are compatible, the plugins can till now have details on installation that are not solved in any case, which generates incompatibilities.

---

### **Final Option**

I am going, because I don't got any answer which answers to my question but got confirmation of workaround :

Uninstall studio 2 and install studio 3 and import projects.

So, for the case, I admit the incompatibility of the two plugins and will uninstall studio2, as you propose.

But, I hope not to get in the future any incompatibility with others modules.

**Conclusion**
Thanks for your answer, which made progress this thread. Nevertheless I think it will be closed when somebody will explain how to install both 2 and 3 version, or say, that's impossible.

Best regards

Trebly